# Strange SNMP v3 response, report instead of get-response

Tags: snmp, sharp-snmp, cucm

Strange problem seen while querying a Cisco Call Manager via SNMP v3.  SNMP v2 works fine.

When using `get-next-request`, the response is supposed to be a `get-response`, but from time to time I get a "`report`" response instead.

Reporting on an `oid` that's got nothing to do with the `oid` in the `get-next-request`.

Dump from wireshark could be provided if interesting. The `oid` in question is (phone update table):

> 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.156.1.2.4.0

Usually the response is a `get-response` with an `oid` similar to:

> 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.156.1.2.4.1.2.580

But every now and then the response is a "`report`" with `oid`:

> 1.3.6.1.6.3.15.1.1.2.0

My application (`.net` using `sharpsnmplib`) reads this as a regular `get-response` and get's all confused. `SNMP v3` encryption and authorization seems to be all good. `CUCM 10.5` and `sharpsnmplib 7.6`.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to spend some time learning SNMP v3, so as to understand what is the "discovery" process and why `REPORT` message is important.

`IdNotInTimeWindow` is just the OID `1.3.6.1.6.3.15.1.1.2.0`, which usually means the time stamp in your request is already out of time window.

Your code should carefully handle such `REPORT` messages (resend the request based on the new time stamp in this `REPORT` message), though I will agree that #SNMP Library should provide better support on that (it's coming, in the next release).

Comment: The solution (in my case anyway) was to simply do a discovery process before each snmp v3 get command.  This is a long-lived process, so I assumed that the discovery report could be used for a (long) period of time.  Using the current version of the library, how could I identify that the get-response is actually a report?  Or even better, how to find the time window from the report message so I can recreate only when neccessary ?  Thanks for your support ;)

Comment: Not easy though. `ISnmpMessage.Pdu().TypeCode` should tell which kind of response message is received, REPORT or RESPONSE. For either message received, you can use it as the last parameter to construct a new request message, such as `GetRequestMessage`. The time window information will be automatically utilized.